# Why I can still access static assets when using gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I just deployed my django app to AWS EC2 instance and change the WSGI server to gunicorn, but I still able to access static assets from browser
(e.g. http://xxx.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/media/aaa/test.jpg)

From my understanding, gunicorn does not serving static files,

can somebody explain why?

Here's the server initialization screenshot:

[gunicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7w22.png)

Comment: I suppose you **1)** either did not re-set your  `STATIC_ROOT`, so the files will still be stored at your previous location where your previous server has access and serves them. Or **2)** you once did execute a `python manage.py collectstatic` with your previous `STATIC_ROOT` settings and those static files still remain at your previous static files location.

Comment: Or, DEBUG is still True; it is not that gunicorn doesn't serve assets, it's that Django itself doesn't serve them if DEBUG is False.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did execute a "python manage.py collectstatic" before and I just deleted the "static" folders then set DEBUG to True. Even cleared browser cache, I still can access the static assets. Is there any suggestions? I do this because I plan to use nginx as reverse proxy, and I need to make sure static assets are served by nginx.

Comment: Sorry for typo, I set DEBUG to False